# Parse Json Data into Existing Flutter Widget

Tags: json, flutter, flutter-layout, rest

hello i am learning flutter now and i am trying to get json data and display it on a carousel widget , below is the full code just so you get an idea of what is going on

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mares/components/drawer.dart';
import 'package:carousel_pro/carousel_pro.dart';
import 'package:mares/components/homecards.dart';
import 'package:mares/pages/contactus.dart';
import 'package:mares/pages/profile.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Elaph Training',
      theme: ThemeData(fontFamily: 'Roboto'),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {


  Future<List> getSlides() async {
    final response = await http.get("http://igh-eg.com/mares/json/slides.php");
    return json.decode(response.body);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget imagecarousel = new Container(
      height: 200.0,
      child: new Carousel(
        boxFit: BoxFit.cover,
        images: [
          AssetImage('assets/slide1.jpg'),
          AssetImage('assets/slide2.jpg'),
          AssetImage('assets/slide3.jpg'),
        ],
        autoplay: true,
        animationCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
        animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 2000),
        dotSize: 5.0,
        dotColor: const Color.fromRGBO(234, 91, 12, 1),
      ),
    );

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        backgroundColor: const Color.fromRGBO(32, 102, 174, 1),
        title: Text('Elaph Training Center'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          new IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.phone_in_talk, color: Colors.white,), onPressed: (){Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new ContactUsPage()));}),//search button
          new IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.supervised_user_circle, color: Colors.white,), onPressed: (){Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new Profilepage()));}),//cart button
        ],
      ),
      //--the end of the app bar--//
      //---start of the drawer---//
      drawer: NavDrawer(),
      body: new ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          new FutureBuilder<List>(
            future: getSlides(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);

              return snapshot.hasData
                  ? new ItemList(
                list: snapshot.data,
              )
                  : new Center(
                child: new CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            },
          ),
          imagecarousel,
          SizedBox(height: 10.0,),
          HomeCards(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ItemList extends StatelessWidget {
  final List list;
  ItemList({this.list});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new ListView.builder(
      itemCount: list == null ? 0 : list.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, i) {
        return new Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: new Card(

              child: new ListTile(
                title: new Text(list[i]['name']),
                leading: new Image.network("http://igh-eg.com/mares/img/${list[i]['photo']}"),
                subtitle: new Text("Description : ${list[i]['desc']}"),
              ),
            ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

currently the data is code is working fine with the listitem class defined above however i want the data to be displayed on the carousel part shown below

```
  Widget imagecarousel = new Container(
      height: 200.0,
      child: new Carousel(
        boxFit: BoxFit.cover,
        images: [
          AssetImage('assets/slide1.jpg'),
          AssetImage('assets/slide2.jpg'),
          AssetImage('assets/slide3.jpg'),
        ],
        autoplay: true,
        animationCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
        animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 2000),
        dotSize: 5.0,
        dotColor: const Color.fromRGBO(234, 91, 12, 1),
      ),
    );
```

any help please? i searched the internet alot and i cannot see what i am missing

Answer (score 3):

I have implemented similar code with `carousel_slider: ^2.2.1` & `cached_network_image: ^2.1.0+1` package.
You can try the code like below:

```
class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  Future<List<Product>> carouselProducts;
  ...
  // method to fecth data from URL 
  Future<List<Product>> getSlides() async {
    return await apiController.carouselDataFetch();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      carouselProducts = getSlides();
    });
  }
```

**Widget in build method:**

```
FutureBuilder<List<Product>>(
    future: carouselProducts,
    builder: (BuildContext cont, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done) {
        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      }
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.none) {
        return Center(
            child: Text("Turn-On Mobile Data / WiFi Please!",));
      }
      if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return Center(
            child: Text("Something went wrong!",));
      }
      return CarouselSlider.builder(
        options: CarouselOptions(
          height: 250,
          autoPlay: true,
          enableInfiniteScroll: false,
          enlargeCenterPage: true,
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          scrollPhysics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
          enlargeStrategy: CenterPageEnlargeStrategy.height,
          autoPlayCurve: Curves.fastLinearToSlowEaseIn,
        ),
        itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          Product prod = snapshot.data[index];
          return CachedNetworkImage(
            imageUrl: prod.productImage,
            fit: BoxFit.fill,
            useOldImageOnUrlChange: true,
            fadeInCurve: Curves.linearToEaseOut,
            placeholder: (context, url) => Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
            errorWidget: (context, url, error) =>
                Icon(Icons.error),
          );
        },
      );
    },
  )
```

**Output:**
[image]

**FYI:**
Change this exemplary code as per your API response data.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys but i found the problem is with the version of the widget i am using so i simply followed the below steps

Step 1: i added the version (carousel_pro: ^0.0.13) to pubspec.yaml

Step 2: Created the below dart file

```
import 'package:carousel_pro/carousel_pro.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Widget CarouselSlider(items) => SizedBox(
  height: 200,
  child: Carousel(
    boxFit: BoxFit.cover,
    images: items,
    autoplay: true,
    animationCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
    animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 1500),
  ),
);
```

then retrieved the data using http,get while initiating the state inside the main.dart as follows

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  var items = [];
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    //get json data function//
    getSlides();
  }

  Future<List> getSlides() async {
    final response = await http.get("http://igh-eg.com/mares/json/slides.php");
    var result = json.decode(response.body);
    result['data'].forEach((data){
      setState(() {
        items.add(NetworkImage("http://igh-eg.com/mares/img/${data['photo']}"));
      });
    });
    print(json.decode(response.body));
    return json.decode(response.body);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        backgroundColor: const Color.fromRGBO(32, 102, 174, 1),
        title: Text('Elaph Training Center'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          new IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.phone_in_talk, color: Colors.white,), onPressed: (){Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new ContactUsPage()));}),//search button
          new IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.supervised_user_circle, color: Colors.white,), onPressed: (){Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new Profilepage()));}),//cart button
        ],
      ),
      //--the end of the app bar--//
      //---start of the drawer---//
      drawer: NavDrawer(),
      body: new ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          CarouselSlider(items),
          SizedBox(height: 10.0,),
          HomeCards(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and it worked like a chart , and a better way is to use the networkcachedimage widget from pub.dev website if you are working with huge data and images

Thank you all and special thanks to @Sanket Vekariya for his help